# My computer turns on when it "sees" me

Tags: electromagnetism, soft-question, energy

Before asking, I swear that, for how it may seem strange, this is all true. Very briefly, when my pc is off and I am near it, it turns on. I do not touch anything. Nobody else have the same effect. I just have to still near it for 3-5 seconds and it will boot. It begun 1-2 weeks ago. The first time was at night, and I was sleeping, so I wasn't really near to it. It is not "scheduled". It doesn't happen at 3:00 every day, just random.

Some days before it started I had a radiography on my head. May I have absorbed some X-rays, which are now creating some sort of magnetic field around me? I'm quite scared from this thing, even if at first it seemed funny...

Thank you in advance, and excuse me for my poor english.

Comment: With great power comes great responsibility...

Comment: Noticed patterns of this kind can be ascribed to 'confirmation bias', whereby you notice events that confirm you're expectations.  Can i suggest you try and carry out a double blind trial to truly measure whether this effect is real.                    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_blind#Double-blind_trials

Comment: @dbrane That was the first thing my mum said when I told her of this. Until I showed this to her...

Comment: @Nic How does Double-Blind work? I read rapidly of it on Wiki, and it seems that I need many people and some researcher... I'd like some fast answer...

Comment: Obviously, this is caused by ghosts.  See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X91ZXqy_8YE for more information

Comment: If you didn't noticed, I wasn't joking... Thanks however... That solved my problem...

Comment: well, either the radiation in your head is causing the computer to come on, or... it's altered your perception of the world. You could try recording what happens in your room via a camera to make sure you're really seeing what you think you're seeing.

Answer (score 4):

Are you referring to some kind of sleep mode, that it comes back if you move the mouse or press any key? If so, the mouse may be moved by perturbations on the table be walking nearby, for example.

If you mean it's actually turning the power on with your presence then I can think of two possibilities: 1- you're lying; 2- someone is playing a prank on you :P

Comment: @AlfaOmega08 Or you are dreaming.

Comment: I almost always leave the computer in hibernation mode, which is restored only when I press the power button. You're right about the mouse and keyboard for sleep mode, but this is not the case. 1) I'm not lying 2) This happened also when I was alone at home. I doubt someone is playing with me. I am an experienced programmer and I know how computers work. But I've never heard of such a thing.